# Having trouble with cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have an Intel NUC with Ubuntu installed. It runs a Minecraft server.
I wanted a simple backup system for the server, and through some Googling I found that I can do so using cron and tar.
However, I seem to be unable to make cron do anything at all.

I made a simple test script for cron to run.

`#!/bin/bash
cd ~/minecraft/Backups
touch bla.txt`

And I modified my crontab by adding this.

`# m h  dom mon dow   command
10 16 * * * /home/ben/minecraft/Backups/Test.sh`

I waited for 16:10 to come and... nothing happened. There was no bla.txt file created. I tried it numerous times by entering different times and still nothing.

The script works when I run it manually. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Instead copy-paste or transcribe the text. Text within images cannot be read by screenreaders (which visually-impaired users might use) nor will Google or other search engines process text within images.

Comment: Is the cron daemon enabled and running? How did you edit your crontab (with `crontab -e` or some other method)?

Comment: Does your script have execute permissions (i.e. what does `ls -l /home/ben/minecraft/Backups/Test.sh` say)?

Comment: @jayhendren
Oh, I didn't realize that screenshots could be problematic. I'll change it shortly.

When I run the command you suggested I get: 
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51 Jan  5 11:37 /home/ben/minecraft/Backups/Test.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but I would suggest you to replace this line:

```
cd ~/minecraft/Backups
```

With this:

```
cd /home/ben/minecraft/Backups
```

Make sure your script has execution permissions:

```
chmod +x /home/ben/minecraft/Backups/Test.sh
```

Check if cron is installed and running:

```
/etc/init.d/cron status
```

If not, install it / start it:

```
apt-get install cron
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

Comment: Oh my! It... it works!
Thank you so much! I had no idea that the change directory thing could be finicky like that.

Comment: Ohhhh. It seems I was making executable the scripts the wrong way...
It's necessary to specify the whole path?

Comment: @user269086 it is not necessary. I used the whole path, since I don't know which is your ``pwd`` ... relative paths are ok as well : )

Comment: Weird. Just now I made executable the backup script again. (My original goal) But this time I specified the entire path. And cron ran the script this time. Well, whatever works.